# Why recreate SSH keys if they are automatically created?

Tags: security, authentication, ssh, client, ssh-keys

I don't understand why, in every tutorial or book I read about authenticating clients to servers using SSH keys, they recreate the pair of SSH keys?

Isn't the pair already created when you install ssh client? like in ubuntu, after doing: `apt-get install ssh openssh-client`, when you go to `/etc/ssh`, you find your keys!

So why regenerate them? and why `ssh-copy-id` doesn't use these keys, in `/etc/ssh` directory?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't the pair already created when you install ssh client?

No, it is not.

> like in ubuntu, after doing : apt-get install ssh openssh-client, when you go to /etc/ssh, you find your keys!

These are not authentication keys, but *server host keys*. If you would install only `openssh-clients`, these keys will not be created. They are created only if you install `openssh-server`!

> So why regenerate them? and why ssh-copy-id doesn't use these keys, in /etc/ssh directory?

Answered above. They are not *authentication keys*, but *server host keys*. Authentication keys are per-user and in your home directory (`~/.ssh/`).